# Transition errors in d3.v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am encountering transition errors upon upgrading to d3.v4.

Please check out the [following fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/axa19gtm/) from Scott White (forked). Try running it in v3, works very nicely. With v4, it breaks, invoking a 'recursive transition uncaught error'.

```
Any ideas?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you look through the [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md)?

The changes I had to make were these:

`.ease(d3.easeSin)` & `.ease(d3.easeBounce)` and change `.each` to `.on`

Here's a link with these modifications: [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lqzxouk/)

Comment: Thanks Robert. Didn't know what a changelog was until you posted your message. This is probably due to overreliance on stackoverflow lol